# Перебор нескольких списков

Tags: c#, framework, .net

Код:

```cs
var list0 = new List<string>() { text = "some"};
var list1 = new List<string>() { text = "text"};
for(var i = 0;i<2;i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(list + i[0]); //будет list0[0]; а после повтора list1[0];
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы `for` перебрал списки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"чтоб for переберал списки", их надо поместить в список.

```
var list0 = new List<string>() { "some" };
var list1 = new List<string>() { "text" };

var lists = new List<List<string>>() { list0, list1 };
for (var i = 0; i < lists.Count(); i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(lists[i][0]);
}
```